# Find New Directory on File System added using SVNKIT

Tags: svn

I've added a new directory on my local file system and I can view it using a svn client when I browse the repository, but I want to see if on the file system.

**Directories under the root svn directory:**

```
README.txt  
db      
hooks
conf        
format      
locks
```

Comment: could you elaborate a bit? its hard to understand your question

Comment: @radai I have added a new local svn repository and then added a new folder and file programaticaly using Java and SVNKit.  I opened a terminal session (mac) to the directory of the repository and I get the folders I have in my original post.  I wanted to know where SVN puts my new directory and file in this local file system.  I can't find the new folder or new file under the new local repository directory.  If I use an IDE that has a built in SVN client and browse the repository I can see my new foler/file under the root of the new svn repository.  Is it not possible to view in the local dir?

Comment: have you tried running "svn update" in your local directory?

Comment: yes, it didn't update with anything, but when I map to it using a svn client it finds the folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what youre seeing is the layout of the svn repository itself, which is exactly as described [in the administration guide](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.basics.html):

- conf/ This directory is a container for configuration files.
- db/ This directory contains the data store for all of your versioned data format. This file describes the repository's internal organizational scheme. (As it turns out, the db/ subdirectory sometimes also contains a format file which describes only the contents of that subdirectory and which is not to be confused with this file.)
- hooks/ This directory contains hook script templates and hook scripts, if any have been installed.
- locks/ Subversion uses this directory to house repository lock files, used for managing concurrent access to the repository.
- README.txt This is a brief text file containing merely a notice to readers that the directory they are looking in is a Subversion repository.

also from the same guide:

> Of course, when accessed via the Subversion libraries, this otherwise
>   unremarkable collection of files and directories suddenly becomes an
>   implementation of a virtual, versioned filesystem

the insternal structure of the svn repository that youre seeing does not reflect the structure of the repository that is exposed to svn clients (like your IDE or svnkit).
you should not be working directly on the svn repository, you should check-out a working copy of the branch youre working on (trunk?) and then you will see your created folders and files.